# Undefined partial derivative with respect to complex conjugate independent of Cauch-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = - \frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$.

This is either undefined or non-zero.

Are the Cauchy-Riemann equations satisfied in the case where this partial derivative is undefined?

Comment: No. The C-R equations literally say $\partial f/\partial \bar{z} = 0$, which is not satisfied if you cannot even compute the derivative.